# Actualizar listado React Native después de elemento borrado

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Buenas tardes compañeros,

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con React Native con la siguiente funcionalidad:

Tipica pantalla (PantallaA) con un listado con elementos. Estos elementos los tengo en un array del state. Cuando selecciono un elemento del listado, me lleva a su correspondiente pantalla del detalle (PantallaB). En esa pantalla tengo la opción de eliminar el elemento. En caso de borrarlo, nada mas hacerlo quiero volver al listado pero que se haya refrescado su contenido.

Ahora mismo lo que haga una vez borrado, es hacer un navigation.goBack(), pero eso no me ejecuta de nuevo el componentDidMount donde llamo al backend para traer de nuevo el listado actualizado. ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo que tienes en la pantallaA y pantallaB, para que sea más facil ayudarte

Comment: @pbalasimon Creo que necesitas un simple CRUD iniciante en react. Puedes buscar eso acá (inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breact%5D+crud o en la internet muy facil https://duckduckgo.com/?q=react+crud&atb=v74-1__&ia=web